# Add default value to a Varbinary column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, varbinarymax

I am trying to set a default value for a column `DefaultImage` in a SQL Server table which is defined as `Varbinary(MAX)`. I've attempted to add the default value both from SSMS and Visual Studio.

```
[DefaultImage] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL
```

However, I am facing a specific problem: when the value I am trying to set is an image with low detail and the length is even, it is stored correctly. But if the image is larger, more detailed, and has an odd length, the value is stored incorrectly and an extra "0" is added.

To illustrate it better https://dbfiddle.uk/ETF0pWuR

```
Correct value:   0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000007...
Incorrect value: 0x089504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000007...
```

As you can see, in the incorrect value, an extra `0` has been added. When I try to decode it from my C# application, an error message is generated indicating that the value is invalid.

If I load the same image from my application and save it in the `ImageDefault` column from the application, it works correctly. The problem only occurs when adding the default value.

Please can you tell me what I can do to add this value by default

Comment: I'm guessing that your default value includes the leading `0x`, leading to the extra nibble.

Comment: Hi @JeremyLakeman, Whether the default includes the leading 0x. The problem is the 0 that is added after the 0x since it leaves it as 0x0.

Comment: How exactly have you defined the default in sql server. Does sql server expect and parse a leading `0x` as defining an integer type, or as part of the hex value, skipping an `x` as noise?

Comment: Have you tried script the table creation with SSMS for both correct and incorrect case and compare them?

Comment: [Seems to work OK for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/-3W2odpm). Can you post the code you are using to actually create the default, this seems pretty integral to solving the issue.

Comment: Thanks @GarethD, your example has helped me to better demonstrate the problem, I just updated the question by adding a link.

Comment: Looks like your incorrect value is offset by a nibble: when you supply a hex encoded `varbinary` literal it needs to have an even number of hex digits after the `0x`, if it has an odd number of hex digits you'll get a `0` padding on the left as you're seeing here. See, for example, [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QAqogORa)